SQL include null with boolean
I'm querying a messy database and want to pull the next appointment for each patient. Because a person can have multiple records with variations they can pull multiple next appointments per person due to the uniqueness of each record. The problem is that I want to keep nulls if a person does not have a next appointment but don't pull the null if they do. I currently have this which works to get one appointment per patient, but because it uses a boolean it drops nulls. This what I have
select distinct  
from a                               
where a.next_appointment = 
  (select 
  min(a2.next_appointment)    
   from a a2 
   where a2.patient_id = a.patient_id 
   and a2.next_appointment > now()
  )                               
or next_appointment is null


Does this do what I want?
If not how can I modify it? Vertica is the SQL flavor.
Thanks!

You probably need to include a small set of sample data (that will match different conditions), as well as what your expected results from the sample.

Plus, I don't quite understand from your description what the data scenario will be - are you saying that there could / will be multiple a records for a patient that might be a combination of "next_appointment" dates in the future as well as "next_appointment" null values?  This is why some sample data would help others to understand exactly what your data looks like

It sounds like you're looking for the next appointment date. I suspect you just want to put that whole subquery into the select list rather than trying to filter on it.

Hi, sorry for the confusion, but I'm looking to do what the SQL above does. Pull the next appointment for each person regardless of other data in the table, but keep records that only have null for next appointment, which my boolean currently drops.

It's hard to tell without some data and expected result, but maybe you want to get a list of next appointments per patient id (nulls included). If so then with some sample data like this:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (PATIENT_ID, SOME_COLUMN, ANOTHER_COLUMN, NEXT_APPOINTMENT) AS
      ( Select 101, 'Something for 101A', 'Something else AAA', DATE '2024-06-25' From Dual Union All 
      Select 101, 'Something for 101B', 'Something else BBB', DATE '2024-06-30' From Dual Union All
      Select 101, 'Something for 101C', 'Something else CCC', Null              From Dual Union All
      Select 102, 'Something for 102A', 'Something else DDD', DATE '2024-06-05' From Dual Union All
      Select 102, 'Something for 102B', 'Something else EEE', DATE '2024-06-19' From Dual Union All
      Select 103, 'Something for 103A', 'Something else FFF', Null              From Dual Union All
      Select 104, 'Something for 104A', 'Something else GGG', DATE '2024-06-13' From Dual 
      )

This was tested with Oracle but should work since :

Vertica 9.1.1-4 now has a built-in function called LISTAGG
As of Vertica 11.0.2, the LISTAGG function supports the WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY clause!

Check for exact syntax in Vertica docs and adjust the code below - replace SYSDATE with NOW() ...
Select   PATIENT_ID, 
         LISTAGG(NEXT_APPOINTMENT, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By NEXT_APPOINTMENT) as NEXT_APPOINTMENTS
From     tbl
Where    Coalesce(NEXT_APPOINTMENT, SYSDATE) >= SYSDATE 
Group By PATIENT_ID

/*      R e s u l t :      (on DATE '2024-06-06')
PATIENT_ID NEXT_APPOINTMENTS               
---------- --------------------------------
       101 25.06.24, 30.06.24              
       102 19.06.24              
       103                                 
       104 13.06.24                         */


Well played, "@d r"!
Only differences Oracle <-> Vertifca:

FROM DUAL is optional and can be omitted
It's LISTAGG( next_appointment USING PARAMETERS separator=', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY next_appointment) AS next_appointments in Vertica


@marcothesane Thanks for helping. Dual is just for sample data - not needed here. Sintax is bit different, but logic is the same. Thanks again.

If you need a single appointment, there is a simpler solution, without correlated query:
select *
from a
where
  next_appointment > now()
  or next_appointment is null
limit 1 over (partition by patient_id order by next_appointment)

If there could be patients with both null and non-null next_appointment, then replace next_appointment in order by with nvl(next_appointment, timestamp '9999-12-31'). Vertica sorts null dates before non-nulls, and this replacement would override this, giving preference to nun-null
